# Does 1,517 shared cM indicate half-siblings?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis, half-siblings

My husband has a close family match of 1,517cM  across 61 segments and his niece shares 906 cM across 40 segments.

Is there a chance this is a half brother to my husband and half uncle to his niece?

Because of age we have ruled out the other possibilities. Because of high connection with his niece also is why we are considering a half brother situation.

What gets confusing is that this match shares a last name as my husband. Wondering if possible while father was serving in WWII he fathered a child he may or may not have known about and mother listed father on birth certificate giving him same last name.

Comment: https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1517 says yes, Half-sibling is possible.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Thank you for having taken the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  It sounds like your additional information will involve living people and so we ask that you take care not to mention their names or any other identifying details, as per our Privacy Policy in the [help].  It seems like you are already being careful not to do that.